# Is Call MagicFunction(intData1, intData2, Dim intData3) a valid statement in vbs?

Tags: vbscript, optional-parameters

I'm not really sure how to phase it any other way.
The thing is, i'm trying to merge functions with the same name in vbs. Sometimes, the function appears in different forms in other parts of the system. If they are too different, I regretfully leave them as they are. However, if the differences are minor (like having one of the functions only having one variable more than the others, which i can then check for in-function), I'd like to add a variable that would be a stand in.

I already know that Optional variables are not possible in vbs, and I've already had experience with passing an array of variants (works like a charm), but I believe this case is a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dim is not correct here. You can do for example:

```
Public Function MagicFunction(intData1, ByRef intData2, ByVal intData3)
    ' some code
End Function
```

and to call it:

```
MagicFunction 3, iCount, ""
```

to have "optional arguments", you can only use an array an parse it (for example using UBound(aTab) to select the correct case

```
Public Function MagicFunction(ByVal aTab)
    Select Case UBound(aTab)
        Case 1: MagicFunction1 aTab(1)
        Case 2: MagicFunction2 aTab(1), aTab(2)
        Case Else: MsgBox "function called with more than 2 args"  '<-- Should never go there
    End Select
End Function
```

With different version of your function depending on the number of argument, MagicFunction1, MagicFunction2... It's ugly but do the trick!

Another possibility is to use empty strings as argument, and define how your function ignore a part when the string is empty (or to be more accurate, call with a specific key, like `"IGNORE_KEY"`)

I hope I'm answering your question!

Comment: Please remember that UBounds start at 0.

Comment: true! but in what I used to copy paste this example, my 0 value is a title, and i didn't removed it. Doesn't change much the code since a UBound(aTab) = 0 would go in the Case Else

Comment: wrong! "UBound(aTab) = 0 would go in the Case Else" ... and lie about the # of args and make you search your code for calls with 3+ args and you'd never find the evil line where you wrote MagicFunction(Array("1,2")) instead of MagicFunction(Array("1","2")).

Comment: yup, the comment would be wrong, you are right. I wrote that in 1 minute to explain how it could work. I'm not lying, I'm inaccurate! and then, if a coder write "1,2", and expect to have sent 2 arguments, that's out of my scope! i know this is not a real nice solution, only a butcher trick to have "optional arguments". i only give an idea here, not a full proper code to be used as it is!

Comment: Supposing i already have this:
'code'Public Function MagicFunction(intData1, ByRef intData2, ByVal intData3)
    ' some code
End Function'code'

but in the particular module that i am going to call the above function, it doesn't have ANYTHING for intData2... so in the function call i decide to declare a variable within it. Like so:
'code'Call MagicFunction(intData1, Dim intData2, 3)

i'm not if this makes it any clearer

Comment: i should probably just pass NULL and then check for it in the common function

Comment: it's not a problem to not have anything in inData2, pass a null string and set up your code to behave how you want when string is empty

Comment: when you declare a function, the arguments are already declared, no need for `Dim`: `ByVal` and `ByRef` are declaration of variables. not putting any is like using ByVal. And i suggest you to have a look to the difference of those 2 call. shortly, ByVal send the value, ByRef the reference, which mean it would change the value of a variable used in the call of the function. Difficult to explain here, but google should be helpful :)

Comment: @Rafiki Thanks, you have been very helpful ^^